# Error: Signature issues when sending XLM via Ledger Blue

Tags: transactions, ledger-blue

As the title suggests. I am trying to send XLM from my Ledger Blue via https://www.stellar.org/account-viewer/#!/dashboard . I have done this numerous times in the past and not had an issue. My firmware and software are up to date on the ledger blue. I am using Chrome. I verified the memo and address I am sending it to and I get to the screen and it says "Check the transaction using your Ledger device.

Submitting transaction to the network..." with the picture of the rocket and I click submit on the Ledger blue and then nothing else happens?

I have also had the following error:

```
{
  type: "https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed",
  title: "Transaction Failed",
  status: 400,
  detail:
    "The transaction failed when submitted to the stellar network. The `extras.result_codes` field on this response contains further details. Descriptions of each code can be found at: https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/concepts/list-of-operations.html",
  extras: {
    envelope_xdr:
      "AAAAAN7JMvKZafqQZzRd41XrftTxZDFnFxfquZrzVf+S7c/2AAAAZAD/sl0AAAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFy9yu0AAAACAAAAAD7iElEAAAABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAADq+QhtWseqhtnwRIFyZRdLMOVtIqzkujfzUQ22rwZuEAAAAAAAAB0aixiYAAAAAAAAAAAZLtz/YAAABA+qSn3Z7nCjEs3qL/512XdzwHSeesRZrmYg5IWVkRfP39D07K8f4QeNnSREDpjXxT+cRUElMM6CiyrBgX1cm/AA==",
    result_codes: { transaction: "tx_bad_auth" },
    result_xdr: "AAAAAAAAAGT////6AAAAAA=="
  }
}
```

I was told the error (when I get it 50/50) was a 
"signature issue". I floated this on Reddit and tried all of the suggestions there: Swapped out USB connector cable, complete recovery mode/reboot of Ledgerblue, reinstall firmware/software, empty cache on Chrome, tried using Opera. I am using a MAC with the latest OS.

Thanks very much for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: I also tried sending this to other addresses as well and it has not worked. Just in case that is a course of action someone would suggest. Thanks again for any help, I have been actively working this issue for 36hrs now. I emailed Ledgersupport yesterday but know they are busy as well. Thanks again.

Comment: When I do get the error above, I have noticed that the first time I hit to confirm the transaction on my ledger blue, the screen blips, then I have to hit the confirm button again to submit the transaction. This then gives me the error page I have provided about signatures. I have been using the ledger to move btc and eth back with no issues so this leads me to believe it is a Stellar specific issue? I also have not heard back from LEdger support and it has been a few days now. Maybe that is normal? Thanks again for the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting the same problem trying to send XLM via the Ledger Blue. I'm also using Chrome on macos. I tried resetting the Ledger Blue using the recovery seed but same problem. It has latest firmware and apps are latest version.

I see the rocket picture and "submitting transaction to network..." but it just hangs there. I didn't get the error message you sometimes see, but the Ledger Blue does blip and ask you to confirm again about 50/50 of the time.

I just restored my seed to my Ledger Nano S to see if it's a Ledger Blue issue, but that has the same issue too.

Answer (score 1):

It does look like you have a bad signature. You can inspect the transaction XDR that you submitted in the Stellar laboratory: [your transaction](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAAN7JMvKZafqQZzRd41XrftTxZDFnFxfquZrzVf%2BS7c%2F2AAAAZAD%2Fsl0AAAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFy9yu0AAAACAAAAAD7iElEAAAABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAADq%2BQhtWseqhtnwRIFyZRdLMOVtIqzkujfzUQ22rwZuEAAAAAAAAB0aixiYAAAAAAAAAAAZLtz%2FYAAABA%2BqSn3Z7nCjEs3qL%2F512XdzwHSeesRZrmYg5IWVkRfP39D07K8f4QeNnSREDpjXxT%2BcRUElMM6CiyrBgX1cm%2FAA%3D%3D&type=TransactionEnvelope&network=public) shows a red cross next to the signature, indicating it is not correct (for comparison, here's an example of one [with a valid signature](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?input=AAAAAODcbeFyXKxmUWK1L6znNbKKIkPkHRJNbLktcKPqLnLFAAAAZAAOHgoAAAACAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFy%2FOrgAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAH4RyzTWNfXhqwLUoCw91aWkZtgIzY8SAVkIPc0uFVmYAAAAADuaygAAAAAAAAAAAeoucsUAAABAQTCOAWW4YMAQzZjrIQUJZM8WVPFCDeFnAZ89uyAmxeo7%2F%2FaMr0f1vPsKNpXiol%2BzzFJ1BkRqHAk3fSIMXBDMDg%3D%3D&type=TransactionEnvelope&network=test)).

Now why is the signature wrong? That's the question. Some possibilities: the hardware may have a corrupt/incorrect secret key. Or it's not being passed to the site correctly. Or there's a bug in the site. Or you need additional signers for the operation in question. One way to narrow this down would be by using a different wallet to submit.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs for possible errors](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html#possible-errors)

> `BAD_AUTH`: Too few valid signatures / wrong network.

This might be an issue with the Ledger Blue, but I see [a commit from January](https://github.com/stellar/account-viewer/commit/db1d2958209aa3f1685b5d6e62833d592a015e09) that purports to fix connection issues with hardware ledger devices.