# Received an update from the Ledger team regarding Stellar withdrawl, they are claiming it is an issue with the Stellar network? Can anyone help?

Tags: ledger-blue

I recently posted a request for assistance on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Stellar/comments/bg0z12/request_for_assistance_sending_xlm_from_ledger/) and [here](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/i-am-apparently-having-issues-sending-xlm-via-from-my-ledgerblue-with-an-error-o) regarding trying to move XLM via my ledger blue and the Stellar Dashboard. After much back and forth with people here, and on other suggested sites, ledger responded that it is an issue with the Stellar network themselves. I have provided the email from Ledger support below. Can anyone here forward this onto the devs that might be able to provide assistance. I did received notice from a couple of other individuals they were having similar issues. Thanks again for any assistance you all can provide.

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for your feedback.
>
> I have checked again the code that you sent and found out that this issue is related to the stellar network.
>
> In fact, Ledger does not have control over Stellar network, unlike BTC and ETH. Regarding this problem, I advise you to contact the Stellar Account Viewer support for more instruction.
>
> Thank you for your understanding.
>
> Best regards,
>   Uyen
>
> Ledger Support

Answer (score 1):

Account viewer issues can be found [here in github](https://github.com/stellar/account-viewer/issues).

Beside some options:

- Did you try it on another computer?
- Did you try Ledger Nano instead? I've absolutely no issues with that one.
- Since account viewer is open source, check out a previous version of the account viewer and see if that works. This way it could get obvious if it's an account-viewer issuer. (Never did, but I think I could do that. When was round about the last time it worked?).
- As a last resort: Key generation is standardized, it's possible to extract your stellar private key and manually sign a transaction to move your lumens. As you can't trust anyone in internet forums be careful with any advice and never type your mnemonic or private keys into a online computer.